# I don't want. (can 'want' be used intransitively?)

Tags: verbs

Can 'want' be used intransitively, as in

I said, "Do you know what we're gonna do for my birthday?" He said, "No, I don't want. What're we gonna do for your birthday?"

This is from 49:27 in Youtube's auto-subs for 'Home Bird (2014) FULL SHOW - Sarah Millican', and I am not entirely sure she didn't say, 'I don't want to.'

Comment: The subs are just wrong. He said, "No, I don't. What're we gonna do for your birthday?" she even repeats the entire exchange & the subs get it right the second time.

Comment: "The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want" means I will not be lacking, a different verb that looks like wanting stuff.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, it’s the same verb, but with an evolved meaning. That earlier meaning is also seen in “Waste not, want not!” And in Franklin D. Roosevelt’s speaking of “freedom from want” as one of his [Four Freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Freedoms).

Comment: You could say "I don't want anything" or "I don't want for anything." One being no desire for more, the other being no lack of. Either way, the subs were just plain ol' *wrong*. That's not what was said. It wouldn't make a rational answer to the question anyway.

Comment: "I don't want to" is much more comprehensible than "I don't want" which makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

*Want* is always transitive, and must take an object infinitive complement. If no infinitive is specified, as in

- *What do you want?*

or

- *He really wants it*.

then the object noun phrase (here *what, it*) is really short for an infinitive  complement clause using *to have*. I.e, if *he wants it*, then really *he wants to have it*, using some sense of *have*, including idiomatic ones:

- *She wants a baby* = *She wants **to have** a baby*
- *He wants a new car* = *He wants **to have** a new car*
- *He wants a big wedding* = *He wants **to have** a big wedding*

Other verbs can be used, of course, but if no verb is provided, *to have* is understood, and can always be added without change of meaning:

- *What do you want (to have)?*
- *He really wants (to have) it.*

Answer (score 0):

"Want" may be either transitive or intransitive depending on its complement. Compare:

> [1] *I want* [*a new car*].
>
> [2] *I want* [*to buy a new car*].

In [1] the complement of "want" is the noun phrase "a new car". It's functioning as object and therefore "want" is transitive.

In [2] the complement of "want" is the infinitival clause "to buy a new car". Clauses cannot normally be objects -- only NPs can perform that function -- so "want" is intransitive.

Comment: Clauses can often be objects, if they're functioning as noun phrases. That's a terminological difference, not anything substantive.

Comment: It seems perverse to classify _want_ as intransitive in the second case, especially since **something** is needed (in your terminology, a complement or an object)

Comment: *Want* —with the meaning of “be in need”—can be used intransitively as in “If you can be as kind and considerate as she is, then you, too, will never want for friends.”

Comment: @ColinFine It's a matter of varying complementation. "Want" takes an obligatory complement, but the complement may be an NP, making "want" transitive, or a non-finite clausal complement in a catenative construction, making "want" intransitive. The distribution of clauses is markedly different to that of NPs so it makes no sense to call them NP objects as Lawler does.

Answer (score 0):

The verb **want** in nearly all contexts is transitive, but there are contexts where it is used intransitively without any express direct object, whether nominal or a clause acting as a nominal.

In ascetic contexts you will find sentences like "The goal is not to want".
And the verb can be used without an object to express the idea of "having desires or yearnings".

[image: William Blake I want]